# What is error 31 in BBx (Business Basic)?

Tags: file-io, basic, business-basic, bbj

I am currently trying to transfer a few thousand records out of a MULTIKEYED file to a flat STRING file, that is building a large SQL INSERT statement to take the data off of our servers FILE bases system to insert into SQL Server for testing.

I have successfully done this with a few other files with a very similar program, but this one keeps producing error 31 workspace overflow, I have tried shortenign the length of the string, the array, and filtering through the file so I only get records with a date newer than Feb 15 2012

here is a snippet fro mthe online help from BBx about error 31:

> !ERROR=31 - Workspace Memory Overflow
> For BBj-specific information, see !ERROR Changes in BBj.
>
> Insufficient workspace memory. Allocating a larger workspace with the START verb can correct this error.
>
> •Attempting to dimension a large string or array.
>
> •Attempting to LOAD a large program.
>
> •Attempting to manipulate a large string.
>
> •Attempting to READ or WRITE a large record.
>
> •Attempting to edit a program that would cause the program to become larger than available memory.
>
> •Attempting to make a program longer than allowed, even if there is enough memory.
>
> •Attempting to enter a console mode command whose compiled length is greater than 256 bytes.

I am fairly confident I am not breaking any of these conditions

any ideas?

```
0001 STRING "/u/x/scc/scott.sql"
0002 OPEN (1)"/u/x/scc/scott.sql"
0004 LET ARRAYLEN=27
0005 DIM A$[1:ARRAYLEN]
0010 OPEN (2)"V1OEMF"
0015 LET K$=""; READ (2,KEY=K$,DOM=0016)
0020 LET K$=KEY(2,END=15000)
0030 READ (2,KEY=K$)A$[ALL]
0035 FOR I=1 TO ARRAYLEN STEP 1; IF A$[I]="" THEN LET A$[I]=".."; NEXT I
0036 FOR I=1 TO ARRAYLEN STEP 1
0039 IF POS("'"=A$[I])<>0 THEN LET A$[I](POS("'"=A$[I]),1)=" "; GOTO 0039
0040 NEXT I
0050 IF A$[14]<"B20215" THEN GOTO 0020
0080 PRINT "INSERT INTO WMS.dbo.V1OEMF VALUES ('"+A$[1]+"','"+A$[2]+"','"+A$[4
0080:]+"','"+A$[5]+"','"+A$[6]+"','"+A$[7]+"','"+A$[8]+"','"+A$[9]+"','"+A$[12
0080:]+"','"+A$[14]+"','"+A$[25]+"','"+A$[27]+"');"
0100 GOTO 0020
15000 CLOSE (1); CLOSE (2)
```

Comment: I used START 2000 to allocate more memory to the program and still get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the `Next I` on line 35 to its own line, it is not getting executed if the `IF` statement is false

Answer (score 0):

to me you should be printing to channel (1) the string file you require. The way you have it now it will simply print to the screen and fill up the memory real quick. Try changing line 80 to Print (1).....etc...

Comment: funny thing is I am writing to the file on channel 1 I only changed it to print for testing purposes to see if it was a certain record that it was failing on, I should have changed it back to write before posting here